# An item with the same key has already been added in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have table with 2 foreign keys. when I am trying to insert duplicate value (for foreign keys) it gives erroe says "An item with the same key has already been added"

below is my code

```
CheckListTrack CheckListtrack = new CheckListTrack();
trackId = entityCollection.WorkItemTrack.Max(p => p.TrackID) ;
foreach (int ListID in tracklist)
{
    CheckListtrack.WorkItemTrackReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("SEIESSEntities.WorkItemTrack", "TrackID", trackId);   // foreign key

    CheckListtrack.CheckListReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("SEIESSEntities.CheckList", "CheckListID", ListID);     // foreign key

    entityCollection.AddToCheckListTrack(CheckListtrack); // error comes after second time control passes here

    }
    curentScope.Complete();
    success = true;
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that you put the same entity for more times to the entity collection. You have to create the new CheckListTrack() entity within the foreach loop. I guess CheckListTrack has its own primary key auto-increment?

Comment: Yes CheckListTrack has its own PK and its auto-increment

Comment: okay than it is obvious. In EF, a new instance for a new entity has to be added for every object. Otherwise, you simple change the foreign keys in your loop, but add the same reference again. This causes the duplicate key exception, which is zero if you did not call SaveChanges meanwhile. An EntityCollection does not allow duplicate keys.